# WebAPI Knockout JS Image Binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, knockout-3.0

I am using Knockoutjs to render a user profile page. For which I am calling a Web API service which returns User details with its Profile Picture.

```
var MessageFrom = {
        FromUserProfileId: self.FromUserProfileId,
        FromUserName: self.FromUserName,
        FromUserPictURL: self.FromUserPictURL
    }




<div id="comments" class="comments" data-bind="with: viewModel">
                    <div class="comment clearfix" data-bind="foreach: Messages">
                        <div class="comment-avatar">
                            <img class="img-circle" data-bind="attr:{'src': FromUserPictURL}" alt="avatar">
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h3 data-bind="text: FromUserName"></h3>
                            <div class="comment-meta"><p data-bind="text: moment(DatePosted).format('LLL')"></p> </div>
                        </header>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <div class="comment-body clearfix">
                                <p data-bind="text: MessageBody"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The URL of the Image returned from WebAPI is Relative URL like  ~/Content/Member/Image1.jpg. While its bind with Image URL shows like "http://sitename.com/profile/~/Content/Member/Image1.jpg".

Everything works great accept Profile Picture

I need to work something on binding as as I cannot change the Path coming from Database.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Regards,

Comment: Show the code that generates the Url. You may need to resolve that path before returning it from the web api. Do you have access to the path in Web Api?

Answer (score 0):

Your binding looks okay. For starters I would use your IE or Chrome developer tools ( F12 ) and change the src manually of the image to find out what exactly works for you.

You say you recieve this: ~/Content/Member/Image1.jpg

Setting the src to this should work: /Content/Member/Image1.jpg

You can change your message object client-side like this, once you're sure what is needed, but I think this should suffice:

```
var MessageFrom = {
        FromUserProfileId: self.FromUserProfileId,
        FromUserName: self.FromUserName,
        FromUserPictURL: self.FromUserPictURL.replace('~','')
    }
```